# Why is 5V Solenoid not working with Pi Pico

Tags: python

I'm trying to control a solenoid with Pi Pico.
Solenoid - https://www.tanotis.com/products/genuine-sparkfun-solenoid-5v-small

I tried following this article (and used USB power and Pico instead of Arduino to control the solenoid)
Here's my circuit photo:
[photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clzzn.jpg) [photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4oW3.jpg) [photo 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7uO4.jpg)

I tried to control the Pico using micropython from my python Thonny interpreter. Here's the code I used:

```
from machine import Pin
>>> led = Pin(1, Pin.OUT)
>>> led.high() # This should have pulled the solenoid
>>> led.low() # This should have brought back the solenoid to its original position
```

Any help here is much appreciated

Comment: Can you post a schematic, the picture is not much help. Show all power supplies as well. You can use a N-Channel MOSFET that is UIS rated with a Vgs less then three volts. Your power supplies need to have there grounds connected. To hookup connect the drain to the solenoid, the other end of the solenoid to the + power supply. Connect source to ground and the gate to the Pi port pin. When using the proper MOSFET a flyback diode is not needed as the MOSFET will adsorb the transient. If the processor port pin is unknown during reset or goes high add a 10K pull down resistor from gate to ground.

Comment: check what pin output actually is with a meter.  then test your mosfet/solenoid combo separately.  only when they both work separately and without causing your power supply voltage to go too low should you even try to put it together.